# Reordering in happens-before relationship of JMM

Tags: java, concurrency, jls, java-memory-model

It is writtem in JLS concerning happens-before relationship of JMM (section 17.4.5):

> It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship
>   between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take
>   place in that order in an implementation.

I am interested in examples of this statement.

Am I understand this right that as an example of this could be the following:

```
Thread 1

x = 1
lock M
y = 2                            
unlock M ----------------------->Thread 2:

                                 lock M
                                 z = 3
                                 w = 4
                                 unlock M
```

Evidently, in this execution trace there is a happens-before relationship between (x = 1) and (w = 4):

```
(x = 1) happens-before (w = 4)
```

Also in this case (x = 1) is ordered with (w = 4) in execution trace.

`Thread 1` does not use variable `w`. Hence, we can place it before (x = 1) without violating the logic of `Thread 1` and `Thread 2`.

Does this mean that if we reorder (x = 1) and (w = 4) then happens-before relationship between those statements preserve?

If you have some other examples please provide.

Comment: Yes that's about it - the hb relationship defines what write operations must be visible to read operations of the same variable across threads - as long as the variable is properly visible when read the hb guarantees are met. If a thread 3 reads w then x, it would be legal for it to read 4 and 0 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right, happens-before relationship holds when independent data changes. As for other examples, don't forget that happens-before applies to the events in the same thread as well. The rule is very simple:

> If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.

So every statement in the Java method happens-before every following statement, but of course JIT-compiler and CPU are free to reorder independent statements (and they are actually doing this quite often to optimize the performance). Sometimes you can observe this reordering from another thread which does not have happens-before relations with current thread.

Comment: What if there is a transitive dependency.. W depends on Q, Q depends on P, P depends on X. You can't ensure that reordering setting of W and X will not cause inconsistencies right?. How does the JVM keep track of such transitive dependencies?

Comment: @TheLostMind, sure it tracks. If tracking is too hard in some case or JVM is not 100% sure, it will just abandon reordering (as you may always execute code without reordering, probably with worse performance). Correctness is absolutely important and cannot be sacrificed for the sake of performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Thread 1 does not use variable w

You can't assume that this is a reason since actually, the Java Memory Model does not take into account whether it's safe to reorder instructions in a thread isolated context, **regarding perception of others involved thread**.
Without locking or memory barrier, JMM only guarantees happens-before of statements **within the same thread**.

In your case, you have a locking mechanism on the same object (M) so the "happens-before" occurs.
`synchronized` (locking) or other atomic variables in Java handles memory barrier **and** atomicity. 
For information, `volatile` variables and `final` variables assignement in constructor only handles memory barrier.

Take this [example](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) for instance, dealing with no memory barrier at all:

```
Class Reordering {
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  public void writer() {
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
  }

  public void reader() {
    int r1 = y;
    int r2 = x;
  }
}
```

> Let's say that this code is executed in two threads concurrently, and
>   the read of y sees the value 2. 
>   Because this write came after the write to x, the programmer might assume that the read of x must see
>   the value 1. However, the writes may have been reordered. If this
>   takes place, then the write to y could happen, the reads of both
>   variables could follow, and then the write to x could take place. The
>   result would be that r1 has the value 2, but r2 has the value 0.

Comment: Yes. But in your example there is no hb relationship. Instead, there is a data race between two threads.